# Pass two results in a sub to another sub

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to pass the result of `x` and `y` from sub `returnIntegerAndBoolean` to sub `testing1`.

In this case, user can run sub `testing1` and return the result "4true" but this doesn't work:

```
Public Sub returnIntegerAndBoolean(ByRef x As Integer, Byref y As Boolean)

x = 2
x = x + 2

If x > 5 Then
  y = False
Else
  y = True
End If

End Sub

Sub testing1()

Dim a As Integer
Dim b As Boolean

returnIntegerAndBoolean a = x, b = y
MsgBox a & b

End Sub
```

Could someone have a look please?

Comment: You have too options, either you write your second Sub in such a way, that it can receive 2 values as input or you write your first sub as a function, which returns an array of two values.

Comment: I have changed the first sub to public function and call the function in second sub but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your calling syntax is incorrect, you pass the result of an evaluation (a equals x) and get a nasty automatic cast from bool instead of a type error.

Instead of:

```
returnIntegerAndBoolean a = x, b = y
```

Use:

```
returnIntegerAndBoolean a, b
```

Or if you want to note the parameters:

```
returnIntegerAndBoolean x:=a, y:=b
```